# How to get the file content in .hg bundler by Python or other tool?

Tags: tortoisehg

for example, I want to use Python or other tool to get the file "test.txt" content in ".hg" which stored by TortoiseHg, but I don't want to clone the ".hg" file to local, I only want to go into this ".hg" and read content without changing anything.

Comment: Do you have an actual local repository or clone of a repository? Its not that clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have the .hg file which is backup by TortoisHg, it's only one file with name ".hg", and I can enter this file, there are some folder like "cache", "store" in it, and also some other files ".i", but I can't read this ".i" file with text reader, it's binary file. I want to get some content in this .i file, but I don't want to make a clone for this bundle ".hg", how should I do?

Comment: That isn't a backup, its the "database", if you will, of the local repository.

Comment: Are you saying that you have committed a file called "test.txt" and you are just trying to get a copy of it so you can read its contents?

Comment: ok, like you said, I list part of content in ".hg" file:
-cache;
-store;
-wcache;
-00changelog.i;
What I want is that I want to get the content in the path: store/data/xxx.i, I want to use Python or other tools to get it,  is it possible?

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: I want to read specific file in this ".hg" to make some additional work, I have a lot of ".hg" backup bundles, so it's not realistic to get the clone of all these bundles, I want to have a automatic script to realize it.

Comment: If you have an .hg folder, then you already have a clone. Why wouldn't you just use the normal mercurial commands to use it?

Comment: If you go into .hg\store\data\ you will find further folders and *.i files which represent the history of all the files ever added to the repository. You can probably read them somehow.

Comment: The problem is there are a lot of ".hg" bundles, If I use clone to get it, I have a lot of manual work to do, but If I only go into the inside of these bundles, the *.i is not readable by text file reader.

Comment: You can use `hg pull` on a bundle file created by `hg bundle` if that's actually what you mean

Answer (score 0):

1. Every `.hg` folder is **not a "bundle"** in terms of Mercurial, it's ordinary repository, without Working Directory only
2. You can (by natural methods) do *nothing* with it, and have to

   - get content of repo in Working Directory (`hg up` in .hg parent dir)
   - make changes
   - commit

in order to get modified repo